# Java application won't exit if serial port is left open

Tags: java, rxtx

I'm using Netbeans to make a jfx app that talks to an arduino Uno. I have installed RXTX on my 64 bit OS X box and it seems to be working.

In the main controller of the application in the initialize() method I do this:

```
 CommPortIdentifier  portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("/dev/tty.usbmodem1d1111");
 this.serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("Box App", 1000);
 // this.serialPort.close();
```

This is great except that when I close the application's only window without calling that `serialPort.close()` function, the app/jvm stays running in the background. I've tried overriding the dispose() method of the controller and adding `Platform.exit()`. 
`Platform.setImplicitExit(true);` is set to true, explicitly.

Not sure what else I can do. If a user closes the app before the serial I/O is done, apparently it will just hang. How can I force the port closed when the application window is closed?

Comment: Is there another callback event, such as the window closing, that you can attach to?

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
   topFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                emsClient.close();
            }
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            }
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            }
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }
            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
            }
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
            }
        });`
```

will help you attach event to close window